# How do I launch server for multiple mocha chai-http test files?

Tags: node.js, testing, mocha.js, chai, chai-http

I am starting my node server in my before block on my mocha chai-http tests.

I have it working perfect for single test files. However when I attempt to run multiple tests in a single command `NODE_ENV=test mocha test/**/*.js` I am getting an error.

I tried to have the node servers launch on different ports per test file. This didn't work, got node server start errors.

I'm now thinking it would be great if I can have a single mocha file that runs before my other test files to start the server and then a single file that runs after the other test files to kill/stop the server.

How would I go about this.

Below is some of my code:

Here is one of my test files for reference:

```
var chai = require('chai');
var chaiHttp = require('chai-http');
chai.use(chaiHttp);
var expect = chai.expect;
var Sails = require('sails');

describe('REST User API', function() {

  var app;    // for access to the http app
  var sails;  // for starting and stopping the sails server

  before(function (done) {
    Sails.lift({
      port: 3001,
      log: {
        level: 'error'
      }
    }, function (_err, _sails) {
      if(_err){
        console.log("Error!", _err);
        done();
      }
      else {
        app = _sails.hooks.http.app;
        sails = _sails;
        done();
      }
    });
  });

  describe("user session", function () {
    var res;  // http response
    var authenticatedUser;

    before(function (done) {
      chai.request(app)
        .post('/users/signin')
        .set('Accept', 'application/json')
        .set('Content-Type', 'application/json')
        .send({ email: 'admin@test.com', password: 'secret'})
        .end(function (_res) {
          res = _res; // Record the response for the tests.
          authenticatedUser = JSON.parse(_res.text); // Save the response user for authenticated tests
          done();
        });
    });

    it("should connect with a 200 status", function () {
      expect(res).to.have.status(200);
    });

    it("should have a complete user session", function () {
      var userSession = authenticatedUser;
      expect(userSession).to.have.property('firstName');
      expect(userSession).to.have.property('lastName');
      expect(userSession).to.have.property('gender');
      expect(userSession).to.have.property('locale');
      expect(userSession).to.have.property('timezone');
      expect(userSession).to.have.property('picture');
      expect(userSession).to.have.property('phone');
      expect(userSession).to.have.property('email');
      expect(userSession).to.have.property('username');
      expect(userSession).to.have.property('confirmed');
      expect(userSession).to.have.property('status');
      expect(userSession).to.have.property('authToken');
    });

  });

  after(function (done) {
    sails.lower(function() {
      done()
    });
  });

});
```

Comment: So where is this error you are getting?

Comment: I am getting a port collision error. Strangely,  I have only two tests and they start the server in the before method on different ports.

`error: Trying to start server on port 3007 but can't...Something else is probably running on that port!`

`Please disable the other server, or choose a different port and try again.`

Answer (score 0):

From mocha `v8.2.0`, you can use [GLOBAL FIXTURES](https://mochajs.org/#global-fixtures) to setup and teardown your web server for all test suites. Global fixtures are guaranteed to execute once and only once.